# How to limit the memory that an application can allocate

Tags: windows, delphi, memory, 64-bit

I need a way to limit the amount of memory that a service may allocate in order to prevent the service from starving the system, similar to the way SQL Server allows you to set "Maximum server memory".

I know SetProcessWorkingSetSize doesn't do exactly what I want, but I'm trying to get it to behave the way that I believe it should.  Regardless of the values that I use, my test app's working set is not limited.  Further, if I call GetProcessWorkingSetSize immediately afterwards, the values returned are not what I previously specified.  Here's the code used by my test app:

```
var
  MinWorkingSet: SIZE_T;
  MaxWorkingSet: SIZE_T;
begin
  if not SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), 20, 12800 ) then
    RaiseLastOSError();

  if GetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), MinWorkingSet, MaxWorkingSet) then
    ShowMessage(Format('%d'#13#10'%d', [MinWorkingSet, MaxWorkingSet]));
```

No error occurs, but both the Min and Max values returned by GetProcessWorkingSetSize are 81,920.

I tried using SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx using QUOTA_LIMITS_HARDWS_MAX_ENABLE ($00000004) in the Flags parameter.  Unfortunately, SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx fails with "Code 87. The parameter is incorrect" if I pass anything other than $00000000 in Flags.

I've also pursued using Job Objects to accomplish the same goal.  I have memory limits working with Job Objects when launching a child process.  However, I need the ability for a service to set its own memory limits rather than depending on a "launching" service to do it.  So far, I haven't found a way for a single process to create a job object and then add itself to the job object.  This always fails with Access Denied.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I think think you need to use jobs for this.

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible for an application to create a job for itself?

Comment: Sure. So long as it's not already in a job.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  For whatever reason, I thought the parameters should be page count rather than bytes.  I overlooked that portion of the docs.  I'll try again.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx) says the min. value must be 20 * page size (ie. 81920 in case of 4K page size) or greater, otherwise the minimum 20 * page size is used. (The values are specified in bytes.)

Comment: David:  My jobs test consist of two apps, one launches the other.  These scenarios work: Launcher creates job, launches child, adds child to job.  Launcher creates job, launches child, child then opens the job created by launcher and adds itself to the job.  So I know that the child is not already in a job prior to my code that adds it to a job.  What I can't get working is a single app that creates a job and then adds itself to the job it just created.  I always get Access Denied (C0000005).  I'm fairly sure it isn't a rights issue, as I did several tests to rule that out.

Comment: Ondrej: I now have SetProcessWorkingSetEx working as I need it to.  Thank you for pointing out my oversight!

Comment: Ondrej: Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: It seems to me you're going about this the wrong way. If you want to write a service that doesn't starve the system, write it in such a way that it doesn't need lots of memory. Considering something like SQL server (as per the question): the reason it uses lots of memory is that it deliberately caches as much data in memory as possible for faster access. Of course it could simply rely on OS swap space when physical memory is exceeded, but that would be less efficient because OS can't use the index tables. So when you configure SQL memory use, you're really just configuring its internal cache.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is **why** do you need so much memory? And can you write your code to use memory more efficiently? Forcing the OS to swap out memory used by your app sooner, or report "out of memory" at a lower bar doesn't really solve the underlying problem.

Comment: PS: Be aware the when you use a blunt instrument to avoiding 'starving other processes of memory', you risk either: creating problems for your own app by not having enough memory; or starving other process of IO resources while the kernel spends more time swapping for your "considerate app". So whatever you do: ***measure and compare***.

Comment: Craig: SQL Server is very sophisticated.  I've often said that it would prefer to be the operating system rather than run on top of Windows.  Yet it allows setting the maximum server memory that you want it to use.  There are valid scenarios where using a lot of memory provides significant benefits, particularly for performance.  Allowing the user or administrator to specify a limit on how much memory the service may be used gives them the ability to make those decisions, rather than the software developer or vendor dictating how the software will perform on their server.

Comment: I removed my initial reply, which may not have made sense without more context.  Basically, we're looking for a roadblock in the event a defect or memory leak is not seen until production, in middle tier services that handle a high user load with varying resource requirements depending on each user's activity.  Personally, I've seen other services bring a server to its knees, so to speak, by starving the server of all physical memory.  We want the ability to set a maximum limit in all scenarios, but especially in the unexpected/undesirable scenarios.

Comment: @JonRobertson Your replies leave me with the distinct impression that you skim-read my comments with your mind already made up. There's no need for you to tell me how sophisticated SQL Server is. In fact the reason for my first comment was that your question's use of SQL Server as an example is technically flawed. Now as the saying goes: "you can lead a horse to water...". So the in light of your 2nd reply, the best I can do is suggest you'll benefit a lot if you reread my 3rd comment carefully, until you truly understand its implications.

Comment: PS: On the whole, the subject matter you're asking about is interesting, but I strongly believe your time would be better spent on testing techniques to ensure the correctness of your program rather than focusing on peculiar esoteric configuration that 99% of admins wouldn't bother with. _All because you're **paranoid** about introducing a memory leak bug._ What about other bugs: threads getting into an infinite loop and starving CPU cores; logging choking disk IO; leaks of 'special' resources like handles and atoms. **None of these are covered by your current approach.** Be more pragmatic. ;)

Comment: @Craig, You make a lot of assumptions in your comments. ;)

Comment: @JonRobertson So says the person who _assumed_ I needed schooling on the sophistication of SQL Server. For the record, I didn't make any assumptions. My comments are based on the information you provided in your question and comments, and my experience in the industry. If you believe I have made any assumptions, perhaps you should reconsider whether there's information about your software you neglected to provide which gives you a different perspective. Regardless, my advice stands: _I don't believe you are taking the most pragmatic (reward, effort, and risk tradeoff) approach._ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`SetProcessWorkingSetSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx) function says:

> dwMinimumWorkingSetSize [in]
>
> ...
>
> This parameter must be greater than
>   zero but less than or equal to the maximum working set size. The
>   default size is 50 pages (for example, this is 204,800 bytes on
>   systems with a 4K page size). If the value is greater than zero but
>   less than 20 pages, the minimum value is set to 20 pages.

In case of a 4K page size, the imposed minimum value is 20 * 4096 = 81920 bytes which is the value you saw.
**The values are specified in bytes.**

To actually limit the memory for your service process, I think it's possible to create a new job ([`CreateJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409(v=vs.85).aspx)), set the memory limit ([`SetInformationJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216(v=vs.85).aspx)) and assign your current process to the job ([`AssignProcessToJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx)) in the service's start up routine.

Unfortunately, on Windows before 8 and Server 2012, this won't work if the process already belongs to a job:

> Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows XP with SP3, Windows Server
>   2008, Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003:  The process must not
>   already be assigned to a job; if it is, the function fails with
>   ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. This behavior changed starting in Windows 8 and
>   Windows Server 2012.

If this is your case (ie. you get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` on older Windows) check if the process is already assigned to a job (in which case, you're out of luck) but also make sure that it has the required access rights: `PROCESS_SET_QUOTA` and `PROCESS_TERMINATE`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a handle to the object containing a process, first use IsProcessInJob() to check if there is a job to be found.  Then use the semi-documented functions ZwOpenDirectoryObject(L"\BaseNamedObjects") and ZwQueryDirectoryObject() to get all the named system level objects and only look a the ones of type L "Job".  Then try to open each such job object with JOB_OBJECT_QUERY access and use IsProcessInJob() to check if it is the right one.  From there, reopen the job with actually needed access bits, recheck IsProcessInJob() (To survive race conditions) and use the handle as needed.

Note that some, but not all Job APIs accept a NULL handle as an alias of the current job, but not all the APIs you indicated you wanted to use.