# is there a way to allocate customized RAM allocation to an user application on Windows?

Tags: windows, memory, 64-bit, customization, ram

I have a custom application running on windows 7 64 bit .
I have tried to reduce the RAM allocation to this exe by

1. editing the registry and setting the values `MaxProcessMemory` - this did not work .
2. I tried installing tools like - `SystemExplorerSetup` & `processhacker` which also did not have any option to change the RAM size.

can anyone help me with this customization ?

Comment: [How to limit the memory that an application can allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725282/how-to-limit-the-memory-that-an-application-can-allocate)